# Bot which interacts with telegram bots

Tags: python, automation, bots, telegram

I was wondering if I can automatically download files from other telegram bots. I've searched online how to make a Python bot (or a Telegram bot written in Python) which do this, but I didn't find anything. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interaction between bots in telegram directly isn't possible since the Bot API doesn't support that.
But you can use MTProto libraries to automate almost all interactions with bots (including file downloading). since these libs simply automate regular user accounts, they don't have the limitations of the bot api.

Here is an example to download a file using [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/) lib :

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = <API_ID>
api_hash = '<API_HASH>'
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

BOT_USER_NAME="@filesending_sample_bot"  # the username of the bot that sends files (images, docs, ...)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: e.is_private))
async def message_handler(event):
    if event.message.media is not None: # if there's something to download (media)
        await client.download_media(message=event.message, )

async def main():
    await client.send_message(BOT_USER_NAME, 'some text or command to trigger file sending') # trigger the bot here by sending something so that the bot sends the media


client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

and in my example I created a minimal telegram bot in javascript that sends a photo (as Document) as it receives any message to test the above script out (but you configure the above script to match with your case):

```
const bot = new (require("telegraf"))(<MY_BOT_TOKEN>);
bot.on("message", (ctx) => ctx.replyWithDocument("https://picsum.photos/200/300"));
bot.launch();
```

Note that you must connect using a regular telegram account (not using a bot token but rather a phone number) for this to work. If using a telegram bot is a must, you can use the script in the background (by running it as a new process or as a REST api, etc...) and return a result to the telegram bot.